# GWT ScrollPanel without fixed units, size issue

Tags: gwt, scroll, size, height

I have an issue with the ScrollPanel...
I tried to use this but it is not filling all the space:

```
scrollPanel.setSize("100%","100%");
```

I read that a fixed height should be given the the ScrollPanel but this doesn't do what I want!

I Have a HorizontalPanel, when I use setSize("100%","100%"); the space is filled, but when I put the horizontalPanel in the ScrollPanel I get this problem.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? because it does not make sense to create scroll panel and set it to 100%. The point of scrollpanel is to provide a penel that wraps it's content into scrollable area.

Comment: So I have this TabLayoutPanel, all the application is in it.
I was doing fine with the HorizontalPanel, but when I resize the browser, there is no scrollBar and it just no more accessible.
So I want to put all the content of the HorizontalPanel in a ScrollPanel that will fill all the space (in that tab), just like the HorizontalPanel did..
I hope I made it a bit clearer.

Comment: Yes exactly! It says that it should be done with absolute CSS units. My question was is there any thing to do to make it fill all the space? Because you know using absolute units for a scrollPanel in my case is not at all a good solution...

Comment: You could calculate the space available Window.getClientHeight() and Window.getClientWidth()

Comment: Is it possible to get the size of the parent and not all the window?

Comment: Yes. Use child.getParent().getOffsetHeight()

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc http://goo.gl/V31VB you should use CSS units but not the percentage.

You could calculate the height/width by using Window.getClientHeight()/Window.getClientWidth().

Answer (score 0):

If scroll panel is not enclosed by another panel and you mention its `height` to `100%`, it takes up `0px` height. If your entire hierarchy leading up to your scroll panels are [layout panels](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#LayoutPanels) then setting `height` to `100%` would had worked, but otherwise you should rework your logic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I am using a TabLayoutPanel which is 100%/100%
the thing that I want to do is simple: I have a TabLayoutPanel, I want to make all what is inside ONE tab in a ScrollPanel. But it is taking exactly the size of the element is that scrollPanel (I want to make it fill the entire space of that tab).
When I use a HorizontalPanel without the scrollPanel, the space is filled(100%/100%) but when I put the intire thing in a scrollPanel it is resized..
I have just started with GWT so take it easy.

Comment: What happens if you put the `ScrollPanel` within the `HorizontalPanel`?

Comment: @enrybo : Thats a  bad design. You should not mix up layout panels and non layout panels. If you do that, then widgets inside your scroll panel won't resize as expected on browser resize or setting of width and height to 100% might not have any effect. This is coming from my own experience

Comment: @HassenCh.: Are you sure that you are not messing up with layout and not layout panels?

Comment: I am mixing thing and I'm starting to loose it... 
Here is an other question: I have a DialogBox and there is a TabLayoutPanel in it, how to adjust the size of the tabLayoutPanel to the size of its components? (
`DialogBox-->VerticalPanal-->TabLayoutPanel--> CaptionPanel-->Grid (with stuf)
       --> CaptionPanel-->Grid (with stuf)
    -->Grid `

I have set the widh of the DialogBox to "auto"
(it is not formatted as I wrote it..