# No Scrollbars in GWT Flextable

Tags: gwt, flextable

I am creating a flextable and adding cells in it dynamically. Flextable is inside scrollpanel but scrollbars never come vertically. They always come horizontally/

```
<g:ScrollPanel ui:field='toppanel'>

            </g:ScrollPanel>
```

Flextable is added in this Scrollpanel dynamically as 
toppanel.add(stutable);

Answer (score 1):

I think you must set the height of your flextable.

Comment: I have tried setting it to 20px just to check this but no success

Comment: What I did was also set the width of scrollpanel but not to 100%, then it worked. The code I added is  toppanel.setHeight("200px");
  toppanel.setWidth("99.9999%");
  stutable.setWidth("100%");

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `RootLayoutPanel` then you need to mention scroll panel height in **px or em**. Don't mention it in percentages. For more info refer the following questions and answers.

[GWT ScrollPanel without fixed units, size issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928496/gwt-scrollpanel-without-fixed-units-size-issue/15934852#15934852)

[GWT ScrollPanel not showing the complete content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282858/gwt-scrollpanel-not-showing-the-complete-content/14290583#14290583)

[GWT: DataGrid - set height 100% not rendering properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845196/gwt-datagrid-set-height-100-not-rendering-properly)

[gwt ScrollPanel in TabPanel: no vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200138/gwt-scrollpanel-in-tabpanel-no-vertical-scrollbar/15216179#15216179)